# Java - automatically set all null String to empty String

Tags: java, string

My program fetch data from external sources and set it to my own created POJO classes. Some external data are returning null while others are returning empty String. The external data has some inconsistency and that is why I want to standardise this part of the program

I'm creating a webservice with java jersey, using Google Gson to convert these POJO classes into json. If the String value is null, gson wont set the member variable into the return json string. This will confuse developers who's using the webservice, as some records won't have certain variable. I could write some code in each pojo setter to check for null and set it to empty String. But I will be introducing boilerplate code

In eclipse, I tried using the code template to check for null String in setter and convert it to empty String.

```
if (${param} instanceof String)
    ${field} = (${param} == null ? "" : ${param});    
else
    ${field} = ${param};
```

However, this won't work if the input type is an int.

Can I customize the code template just for String input? 
Is there other ways to automatically do this?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea to set globally. *Why* are you wanting to replace nulls with empty string, especially instead of using an `Optional`?

Comment: You don't want to do this at all. There is a big difference between a blank line and end of file.

Comment: An empty JSON value is more confusing and less efficient than omitting the attribute altogether, which is why GSON behaves the way it does. If the String really has a default value, then set that value in the POJO class.

Comment: Hi, I did initialise a default value to the member variable during declaration in the POJO class. My program fetch data from external sources and set it to my own created POJO classes. Some external data are returning null while others are returning empty String. The external data has some inconsistency and that is why I want to standardise  this part of the program

Comment: You should get GSON to serialize `null` values as such in JSON, rather than provide this sort of workaround in your code. If that is not possible (I strongly doubt it), you should probably consider using Jackson or some other JSON library.

Answer (score -2):

All you need is to write separate code for int type input.
Try using some filter condition for the both(int and String) kind of request.

int cannot be cast to String. String priority is higher then int.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate more? Do you mean writing separate code in the eclipse template? Any sample code or steps?

Comment: What's "string priority" ?

Comment: Here priority, i mean to say that String is object type and int is primitive type. So int cannot be cast to String.